# Variable substitution parsing error (unexpected token, expected "...")

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx, create-react-app

I have some code which dynamically adjusts a text field.

This version of the code ***works ok***:

```
  if (props.responsetxt === null) {
    txtField = (
      <TextField
        autoFocus
        margin="dense"
        id="name"
        label={emailField}
        type="email"
        fullWidth
        onChange={e => emailFieldUpdate(e)}
      />
    );
```

However I am using `material-ui` and I want to make use of their `error` option (https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/)

But if I modify my code as follows :

```
let errorFlag = null;  // add this
    txtField = (
      <TextField
        {errorFlag} // add this
        autoFocus
        margin="dense"
        id="name"
        label={emailField}
        type="email"
        fullWidth
        onChange={e => emailFieldUpdate(e)}
      />
    );
```

I get an error:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..."

```
  Line 45:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..."

  43 |     txtField = (
  44 |       <TextField
> 45 |         {errorFlag}
     |          ^
  46 |         autoFocus
  47 |         margin="dense"
  48 |         id="name"
```

I do not understand why `label` and `onChange` dynamic parameters can work OK but the `{errorFlag}` substitution cannot ?

**UPDATE**

```
function DownloadForm(props) {
  const intl = props.intl;
  const boxTitle = intl.formatMessage({ id: 'downloadRequest.title' });
  const cancelButton = intl.formatMessage({ id: 'button.cancel' });
  const closeButton = intl.formatMessage({ id: 'button.close' });
  const downloadButton = intl.formatMessage({ id: 'button.download' });
  const emailField = intl.formatMessage({ id: 'downloadRequest.emailField' });
  let boxText = null;
  let waitingAnimation = null;
  let returnArr = {};
  let errorFlag = null;
  const emailFieldUpdate = e => {
    returnArr['email'] = e.target.value;
    if (!EmailValidator(e.target.value)) {
        console.log('setting true !');
        errorFlag=true;
    }
  };
  returnArr['subset'] = props.selectedSubset;
  if (props.showWaitingAnimation) {
    waitingAnimation = <CircularProgress />;
  }
  if (props.responsetxt === null) {
    returnArr['correlID'] = UUIDGenerator();
    returnArr['boxOpened'] = TAI64.now().toHexString();
    boxText = intl.formatMessage({ id: 'downloadRequest.prompt' });
  } else {
    boxText = props.responsetxt;
}
  let txtField, submitButton, closeText;
  if (props.responsetxt === null) {
    txtField = (
      <TextField
        error={errorFlag}
        autoFocus
        margin="dense"
        id="name"
        label={emailField}
        type="email"
        fullWidth
        onChange={e => emailFieldUpdate(e)}
      />
    );
    submitButton = (
      <Button
        color="primary"
        onClick={() =>
          props.submit(returnArr, process.env.REACT_APP_ITS_AWS_SQS_DOWNLOAD)
        }
      >
        {downloadButton}
      </Button>
    );
    closeText = cancelButton;
  } else {
    closeText = closeButton;
  }
  return (
    <div>
   <Dialog open={props.open} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">{boxTitle}</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>{boxText}</DialogContentText>
          {waitingAnimation}
          {txtField}
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button color="primary" onClick={props.close}>
            {closeText}
          </Button>
          {submitButton}
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
export default injectIntl(DownloadForm);
```

Comment: try `error={errorFlag}`

Comment: @ic3b3rg unfortunatley as with Treycos suggestion, this does not have the desired effect. have updated my q to show.

Comment: You need to set `errorFlag` in the render function - it doesn't look like that's where you're setting it since `e.target.value` is not available in the render function

Comment: Does `emailFieldUpdate` update a state variable which holds the email? If so, use `error={!EmailValidator(this.state.<< email field >>)}`

Comment: @ic3b3rg have updated my q with more code which might give you the context you need ?

Comment: You've created a stateless component - you need to convert this to a stateful component to get the `TextField` to work the way you want - see https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc :

```
  <TextField
      error
      id="standard-error"
      label="Error"
      defaultValue="Hello World"
      className={classes.textField}
      margin="normal"
  />
```

The `error` here is the short syntax of `error={true}` which is not possible to reproduce dynamically.
However, you can do the following :

```
  <TextField
    error={errorFlag}
    autoFocus
    margin="dense"
    id="name"
    label={emailField}
    type="email"
    fullWidth
    onChange={e => emailFieldUpdate(e)}
  />
```

And as your error message is telling you, deconstructing a single attribute JSON may also work :

```
  <TextField
    ...{error : errorFlag}
```

Renaming it to `error` will reduce the syntax even further :

```
  <TextField
    ...{error}
```

---

EDIT :

You are using a stateless React component, which means that it is never going to re-render by itself, and calling `emailFieldUpdate` won't either. I refactored your component into a stateful one, where `errorFlag` is now in your state.

Calling `this.setState({ errorFlag: true })` will update your flag and rerender your component, showing you the error. I also made few code readability changes :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
export default class DownloadForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            errorFlag: null,
            returnArr: {}
        }
    }

    emailFieldUpdate = e => {
        this.setState({ returnArr:{ email: e.target.value }})
        if (!EmailValidator(e.target.value)) {
            console.log('setting true !');
            this.setState({ errorFlag: true })
        }
    };

    render() {
        const { selectedSubset, responsetxt, showWaitingAnimation, intl, submit, open, close } = this.props //Decontructs your props
        const { errorFlag, returnArr } = this.state //Deconstructs your state

        const [boxTitle, cancelButton, closeButton, downloadButton, emailField] = 
        ['downloadRequest.title', 'button.cancel', 'button.close', 'button.download', 'downloadRequest.emailField'].map(id =>
            intl.formatMessage({ id })
        );
        let boxText = null;
        let waitingAnimation = null;

        returnArr['subset'] = selectedSubset;
        if (showWaitingAnimation) {
            waitingAnimation = <CircularProgress />;
        }
        if (!responsetxt) {
            returnArr['correlID'] = UUIDGenerator();
            returnArr['boxOpened'] = TAI64.now().toHexString();
            boxText = intl.formatMessage({ id: 'downloadRequest.prompt' });
        } else {
            boxText = responsetxt;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <Dialog open={open} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
                    <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">{boxTitle}</DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent>
                        <DialogContentText>{boxText}</DialogContentText>
                        {waitingAnimation}
                        {!responsetxt && 
                            <TextField
                                error={errorFlag}
                                autoFocus
                                margin="dense"
                                id="name"
                                label={emailField}
                                type="email"
                                fullWidth
                                onChange={this.emailFieldUpdate}
                            />
                        }
                    </DialogContent>
                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button color="primary" onClick={close}>
                            {responsetxt ? closeButton : cancelButton}
                        </Button>
                        {!responsetxt && 
                            <Button
                                color="primary"
                                onClick={() => {submit(returnArr, process.env.REACT_APP_ITS_AWS_SQS_DOWNLOAD)}}>
                                {downloadButton}
                            </Button>
                        }
                    </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

You seem to be using React-intl, look at this documentation to make your messages directly into your JSX : https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Components#formattedmessage

Also I suggest reading [conditional rendering in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) and [deconstruction in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: I tried your suggestion, however it does not seem to behave (dynamically altering has no effect on the field), I will update my original q with the detail.

Comment: Just seen your edit : Shouldn't `errorFlag` be in your state ? Where is your `if` condition in your class ? Can you show a little more code ?

Comment: I have updated my original q with the full code (i've only omitted the import section to keep it short).

Comment: I'll check it out tomorrow

Comment: Thank you for this. I will go try it and update you in due course.  In the mean time, you said "stateless React component, which means that it is never going to re-render by itself".  Whilst I don't dispute your understanding of the subject (which is obviously greater than mine !), I'm confused as to why some stuff would work stateless (e.g. the rendering of the waiting animation or display of result text) and other stuff wouldn't (i.e this `Error` thing).

Comment: An animation can entierely be made out of CSS, and not JS. Although some loaders use JS, they will re-render themselves using `setState` when they want to update what will be shown to the user. Stateless stuff are components that never update what their render function uses

Comment: Thanks.  Just working on testing your code now.  I think you forgot to put `returnArr` into state, but I'm refactoring that, no biggie.  Also I don't think `intl` gets recognised unless `export class DownloadForm extends Component ` and then separately `export default injectIntl(DownloadForm)`

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you want to change any variable that you're using in your render function, put this variable in a state and make your component stateful.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought the rule of thumb was to only use states when you wanted to use "lifecycle methods" like `componentDidUpdate()`.  But what you say makes sense.

Comment: You're right, this is also another reason to need a stateful component, although requiring this function usually means that you already have a state. I took the code review a little further and fixed a few mistakes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186232/discussion-between-little-code-and-treycos).